# Organizing & sorting columns into dictionary variable

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a stats.csv file with multiple columns, the first 2 columns of which are (note: I have not included the rest of the table as it contains confidential data):

```
USER        TEAM

UKW1G1KK8   TFCARKGN5

UL3DTLGRE   TFCARKGN5

UL2HHLQRY   TFCARKGN5

ULTM136EB   TFCARKGN5

UFD51MS69   TFCARKGN6

UKM4K5DJR   TFCARKGN6

UMS5G3PEH   TFCARKGN6

UL7RL2X5E   TFCARKGN6

UMP69CC69   TFCARKGN6
```

I wish to create a dictionary like this: `current_teams = {team: [users]}`.

In the above example it would be

```
current_teams = {TFCARKGN5:[UKW1G1KK8,UL3DTLGRE,UL2HHLQRY,ULTM136EB],  TFCARKGN6:[UFD51MS69,UKM4K5DJR,UMS5G3PEH,UL7RL2X5E,UMP69CC69]}
```

I wrote this

```
import csv
stats = {}
with open('Data/stats.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader: stats.update({row['USER']: row})

current_teams = {}
members = []
for user_id, team in zip(list(stats.keys()), [stats[user]['TEAM'] for user in list(stats.keys())]):
    current_teams = {team:{'members':members.append(user_id)}}
```

But the output I get is this: `{'TFCARKGN5': {'members': None}}`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what prints `for user_id, team in zip(list(stats.keys()), [stats[user]['TEAM'] for user in list(stats.entries())]):
    print(user_id,team)
    current_teams = {team:{'members':members.append(user_id)}}` ?

Comment: can you also add a print of `stats`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the simplest and most Pythonic way of doing this was staring at me all along! You don't need to import additional modules (other than `csv`). Just do this:

```
import csv
stats = {}
with open('Data/stats.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader: stats.update({row['USER']: row})

current_teams = {}
for user_id in list(stats.keys()): 
    if stats[user_id]['TEAM'] in current_campaign: current_campaign[stats[user_id]['TEAM']]['USER'].append(user_id)
    else: 
        current_campaign.update({stats[user_id]['TEAM']:{'USER':[]}})
        current_campaign[stats[user_id]['TEAM']]['USER'].append(user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve, but I see that you use `members.append(user_id)` as the value in your dict, but `.append()` does not return a value.

I think this code achieves the grouping you are looking for (I read it as a text file, but you can also use the `csv` module if you prefer):

```
import collections
teams = collections.defaultdict(set)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0:
            # skip first line
            continue

        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            user, team = line.split(',')
            teams[team].add(user)

print(teams)
for t, user_set in teams.items():
    print(t, user_set)
```

The output is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'TFCARKGN5': {'ULTM136EB', 'UKW1G1KK8', 'UL3DTLGRE', 'UL2HHLQRY'}, 'TFCARKGN6': {'UFD51MS69', 'UMS5G3PEH', 'UKM4K5DJR', 'UMP69CC69', 'UL7RL2X5E'}})
TFCARKGN5 {'ULTM136EB', 'UKW1G1KK8', 'UL3DTLGRE', 'UL2HHLQRY'}
TFCARKGN6 {'UFD51MS69', 'UMS5G3PEH', 'UKM4K5DJR', 'UMP69CC69', 'UL7RL2X5E'}
```

Comment: How do I use the csv module?

Comment: @CodeMonkey you can find many online tutorials for Pythons built-in [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), for example this one https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. I have use a `txt` file instead of `csv`. You can read the `csv` file with `csv` Python module. Probably this site can help: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

**test.txt**

```
UKW1G1KK8   TFCARKGN5

UL3DTLGRE   TFCARKGN5

UL2HHLQRY   TFCARKGN5

ULTM136EB   TFCARKGN5

UFD51MS69   TFCARKGN6

UKM4K5DJR   TFCARKGN6

UMS5G3PEH   TFCARKGN6

UL7RL2X5E   TFCARKGN6

UMP69CC69   TFCARKGN6
```

**Code:**

```
result_dict = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for data in f.readlines():
        data = data.strip()
        if not data:
            continue
        if data.split()[1] in result_dict:
            result_dict[data.split()[1]].append(data.split()[0])
            continue
        result_dict[data.split()[1]] = [data.split()[0]]
print(result_dict)
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{'TFCARKGN5': ['UKW1G1KK8', 'UL3DTLGRE', 'UL2HHLQRY', 'ULTM136EB'], 'TFCARKGN6': ['UFD51MS69', 'UKM4K5DJR', 'UMS5G3PEH', 'UL7RL2X5E', 'UMP69CC69']}
```